# Using O_RDWR vs O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY

Tags: c++, linux

In my simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "What does the quick brown fox say?" << endl;

    int file_descriptor = open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY);
    write(file_descriptor, ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().size());
}
```

I open the terminal stream using the combination `O_RDONLY` | `O_WRONLY`, and this seems to work fine. I get that you *should* use `O_RDWR` because it makes clearer semantic sense, but my question is why bother creating a whole other flag if joining two existing flags already works? Is there some historical reason for this, or am I just overlooking something, and this really doesn't actually work?

Comment: It isn't 'clearer semantic sense'. It's different. Read-only and write-only are mutually exclusive. Using them both together is semantic nonsense.

Comment: @EJP Not with the chosen names, but dropping the ONLY and specifying that no access mode at all implies that you only can do fstat, is a much cleaner interface.

Comment: O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY == O_WRONLY;  because 0 | 1 == 1. In your sample you only write, so you won't notice any problem.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY` (at least on my Linux machine) is not the same thing as `O_RDWR`.

```
#define O_RDONLY         00
#define O_WRONLY         01
#define O_RDWR           02
```

The fact that it works seems like a bug/feature/coincidence rather than "it works because it should work that way".

Comment: IIRC it is the case that `(O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY) != O_RDWR` on basically all Unixes going back at least as far as 4BSD, although it appears not to have been the case in the primordial soup (see e.g. http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/src/sys2.c.html#line5799 )

Comment: And of course, he didn't test reading, so he doesn't know whether it really worked or not.

Comment: FWIW: Posix says "Applications shall specify exactly one of the first five values (file access modes) below in the value of oflag:" where the five are `O_EXEC`, `O_RDONLY`, `O_RDWWR`, `O_SEARCH` and `O_WRONLY`.

Comment: It's gotta be that way, otherwise you can't tell them apart (see Jack Miller's comment above... 0 | 1 == 1).

Answer (score 1):

From Linux manual page for open(2):

> Unlike the other values that can be specified in flags, the
> access mode values O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, and O_RDWR do not specify
> individual bits.  Rather, they define the low order two bits of
> flags, and are defined respectively as 0, 1, and 2.  **In other
> words, the combination O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY is a logical error,
> and certainly does not have the same meaning as O_RDWR.**